# Table column expand width based on content

Tags: html, css, width, column-width

There is a table in my page, with  5 columns overall. 3 of these columns have static width, and the rest of them have dynamic width based on their content.
I've set `max-width` to 170px, and `min-width` to 50px. However, two strange thing happen:
1-

1. in inspect, I can see that `min-width` (when cell is empty) is 188px, and `max-width`(when any extra character will cause a break word) is 408px.
2. When span consists of a very small piece of texts, like just a word, it gets a considerable padding from left and right, but in inspect I see `padding:0` for every direction.

I know that my span is not set to `display:block`and its width is equal to the text inside it. So there must be something wrong with my column.

an instance of what happens can be seen in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0HPN.png).

[image: each column width is written on it]

Since I'm not sure which class or style caused this, I copied every style this dynamic column has received from inspect window, and put it here. I also marked those I thought would be relevant:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-user-select: none;
border-bottom-color: rgb(27, 25, 57);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(27, 25, 57);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(27, 25, 57);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-top-color: rgb(27, 25, 57);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 2px;
**box-sizing: content-box;**
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
direction: rtl;
**display: table-cell;**
font-family: iran, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 28.08px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 44px;
line-height: 37.1429px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
**max-width: 170px;**
**min-width: 50px;**
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
**position: relative;**
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
**white-space: normal;**
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

What I've tried by now:

- `white-space : pre`; Not only adds extra padding to left and right, but also to the other two directions, too. Couldn't test
- `width:100`; Although solves the extra padding issue, only lets the width to expand in inspect window, and prevents dynamic width in run time.
- Alternating span with a div and set `display:inline`; no difference. `margin:zero`, also no progress. Negative solves the problem for short spans, but lets longer spans to overflow the cell, which was predictable.

Any attempt to help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

edit: [This is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1Lu8az2/) which shows what happens. The **padded one** is the one which receive an extra padding from nowhere... or somewhere I can't see.

Comment: min and max-width are not efficient on table elements (or display:table family rules). Basicly a table expands and shrinks according to its content. It cannot show a scrollbar unless you reset display and then you loose the table-layout properties. You can set fixed width via  `table-layout:fixed` and if no width set, columns might be spread evenly. You can start to read this https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/table-layout to understand better how table behaves.

Comment: well, I don't want my table cell to expand more than a specific width, and I had to set max-width to make span break into two lines after that. If I don't initialize min and max, still I get the same result, but it expands until it gets all free space available.

Comment: To override this behavior you can unfortunately add an extra wrapper in your cells to which you can set the minand max-width. , do not set a width to the table itself. It will size then according to the space used by the wrappers within . hope this helps even it was not what you expected. :(

Comment: I placed a div inside this cell, and put my text inside it. Still the same extra padding is set to it. I mostly need to eliminate that damn padding :D why does it occurs in the first place?!

Comment: um...yes, I'm not sure I completely understood what you mean. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***Answer made from the earlier comments:***

---

min and max-width are not efficient on table elements (or display:table family rules).

Basicly a table expands and shrinks according to its content. It cannot show a scrollbar unless you reset display and then you loose the `table-layout` properties. 
You can set a fixed `width` via `table-layout:fixed` and if no `width` set, columns might be spread evenly.

You can start to read this http://w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/table-layout to understand better how `table` behave.

> well, I don't want my table cell to expand more than a specific `width`, and I had to set `max-width` to make span break into two lines after that. If I don't initialize min and max, still I get the same result, but it expands until it gets all free space available. – Sarah Amini

To override this behavior you can unfortunately add an extra wrapper in your cells to which you can set the min and max-width. , do not set a width to the table itself. It will size then according to the space used by the wrappers within .

> I placed a div inside this cell, and put my text inside it. Still the same extra padding is set to it. I mostly need to eliminate that damn padding :D why does it occurs in the first place?!

to shrink the cells as much as min-width, you can set `width:XX` to tds, width here actually means min-width for a table-cell (remenber it expands to content size)

In that case , do not set `table-layout:fixed;` The cells  will at first(if empty for instance) be XX width and can expand.
It will be able to grow untill the div reach its `max-width`.

Below a made up example which might not be alike your own structure ....

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin:1em auto;/* will not affect tds */
}

td {
  width: 50px; /* equals min-width */
}

td>div {/* each div can have a different value set via a class or td:nth-child(x)> div*/
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden; /* ? */
  min-height: 1.2em;
}
/* not all the same ? */
td:nth-child(3) {
width:100px;
}
td:nth-child(3) > div{
max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td><div></div></td><td><div></div></td><td><div></div></td><td><div></div></td><td><div></div></td></tr></table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>LOREM PIXEL BLABLUM
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>LONGERPIECEOFCONTENT
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><div></div></td><td><div></div></td><td><div></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tested something likethis on my original table, and my table cell gets stuck in the width I initial like your td:nth-child(3) {
width:100px;
} part. :| I really don't have any clue what's happening here :|

Comment: @SarahAmini maybe it is time to  share a piece of your table(you may use lorem ipsum text and fake image) and the css you apply for the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be necessary, since there are several files which are setting and overwriting styled on table elements. I added a jsFiddle to my question, and hope it contains all styles. at least it behaves the same as my output! Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: @SarahAmini :(, it was only about selector's weight and text-align i suppose : https://jsfiddle.net/x1Lu8az2/2/ (with a div to emulate min/max-width https://jsfiddle.net/x1Lu8az2/1/)

Comment: I commented min-width of dynamic-cell from your second fiddle, and got the desired result. however for some reason, in my app it still doesn't work